# PHP - Array content in variable

Tags: php, arrays, variables, syntax-error

I have an array:

```
$people = "array(
    "t1:sdfdsf774",
    "t2:dsfdsf",    
);
```

I have a variable called $content which holds the array content.

I am trying to get $content into the array as follows:

```
   $people = "array(".$content.")";
```

I keep getting a syntax error.

Comment: `array($content)`; maybe

Comment: You're creating a string.. not an array. When you define an array, you do it like this: `$people = array("something", "something else");` Read the documentation: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php (which should be your first stop, before asking here).

Comment: Really unclear... What do you want to achieve by doing this?

Comment: So you want `$people = array($content)` or `$people = $content`; This is surely not worth writing an actual answer for....

Comment: Also, you $people assignment at the beginning has a quote mark at the start, which would cause an error.

Comment: Some feedback from the OP would be nice.

Comment: $content contains "t1:sdfdsf774",
    "t2:dsfdsf",   When I do $people = array ($content), I get an error (It's a Twilio error - this is for Twilio) - : Uncaught exception 'Twilio\Exceptions\RestException' with message '[HTTP 400] Unable to create record: The 'From' number messenger:1744126135864793 is not a valid phone number, shortcode, or alphanumeric sender ID.'

Comment: @CodyRaspien Ok, that is completely different to what you have said in your question! You have quote marks all over the place and didn't mention Twilio or the exception anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

In the first place why are you using "" to define an array?

`$people = "array(".$content.")";` In this type of deceleration, what exactly is happening is the string "array(" is being concatenated to array $content which cant happen.

The array can be initialized as (observe no quotes)

```
$people = array("t1:sdfdsf774", "t2:dsfdsf");
```

This creates an array as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => t1:sdfdsf774
    [1] => t2:dsfdsf
)
```

If this is how u are trying to create. Now if you want to add $content to $people, then use array_merge as following:

```
$people = array_merge($people, $content)
```

If you want t1 and t2 as keys, then you should initialize the array as follows:

```
$people = array(t1=>"sdfdsf774", t2=>"dsfdsf");
```

This the following is created:

```
Array
(
    [t1] => sdfdsf774
    [t2] => dsfdsf
)
```

Then array_merge with $content.

To append the array to $people, use `array_push($people, $content)`. No deceleration is required.